# Netsuite - ability to upsert/update invoice line items?

Tags: netsuite

I need to be able to upsert line items in a NetSuite invoice with updated information from an external system.

I am creating an invoice in NetSuite with the payload:

```
{
"tranDate": "2021-07-12", 
"dueDate": "2021-07-19", 
"externalId": "sysA_INV-34698", 
"amountPaid": 0, 
"entity": {
    "id": 3127
},
"item": {
    "items": [ 
        {
            "item": { 
                "id": 374
            }, 
            "internalId": "sysA_INV-34698_JOBID-4875398"
            "quantity": 1, 
            "rate": 534.54
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I would like to upsert this **line item** using the internalId but it doesn't appear to be saved against the line item, therefore I cannot  target it. Is it possible in NetSuite to upsert/update a line item, or do I have to remove them all and recreate them every time there is new data from the source system?

Comment: internalId on the line item? No such thing.

Comment: There are many ways to get data from/into with NetSuite, which method are you using (SuiteScript, REST Web Services, etc...)?  That is necessary info to reference the correct API/Language to insert line items on an invoice.

Comment: I am using the REST Web Services. I think I have my answer - once an invoice is created and the line items are defined, that is essentially fixed. You cannot adjust the line item, just remove and recreate.

Comment: @user1048175 I've come to the same conclusion... below I added a way to at least do that in a single PATCH request

Answer (score 0):

To update a specific line item, use the `itme.items.line` field.  That will let you target a specific line for updates.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same as an upsert, but this at least can get it done in one call, assuming you always know the previous items.

With the NetSuite REST API you can overwrite the items without appending by submitting a `PATCH` request with parameters `replaceSelectedFields=true` and `replace=item`

Thus your request url might look like

> PATCH .../invoice/{id}?replaceSelectedFields=true&replace=item